# Hard clipper in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to make a hard clipper in matlab, using the function

```
f(x)= -1 for x<=-1
       x for -1<x<1
       1 for x>=1
```

But I have absolutely no idea about how to do this. I get a vector X which is supposed to go through this klipper..

Should I write some kind of a for-loop such as:

```
for n=1:length(x):
     y(n)=x(n)=x for -1<x<1
```

Or how should I do this? Really struggling, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Several ways to do this. With a for-loop:

```
y = x;
for i = 1:length(y)
    if y(i) > high_value
        y(i) = high_value;
    end
    if y(i) < low_value
        y(i) = low_value;
    end
end
```

With boolean indexing:

```
y = x;
y(y > high_value) = high_value;
y(y < low_value) = low_value;
```

Vectorized one-liner:

```
y = max(low_value, min(high_value, x);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! How would I go about adding something like

if y(i) > high value
           y(i) = new_value
if y(i) > low_value
           y(i) = new_value2

and for the i's that are between high_value and low_value I set new_value3?